# How to reset timer to 0 in React Native?

Tags: react-native, timer

I have a project that will display a Video if user don't touch the iPad screen after 10 seconds.
I have two screens **HomeScreen** and **VideoScreen**, **HomeScreen** will display by default and **VideoScreen** will display after 10 seconds after user don't touch the screen. Here is what I have tried so far, but it din't work

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        displayVideo: false
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    var timer = setInterval( () => {
        this.updateState();
    }, 10000);
  }


resetInterval() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = setInterval( () => {
        this.updateState();
    }, 10000);
}

updateState = () => {
    this.setState({displayVideo:true});
}
```

I want to update **displayVideo** to **true** when 10 seconds has passed, but if user touch on screen will reset it and restart it again.

Thanks you very much for any help.

Comment: What didn't work?  What does your touch handler look like?

Comment: <TouchableHighlight 
                onPress={() => this. resetInterval()} 
                style={styles.videoContainer}>
                <Video 
                    source={require('../video.mp4')}
                    paused={false}
                    resizeMode="cover"                     
                    repeat={true}    
                    style={styles.backgroundVideo} />  
            </TouchableHighlight>

Comment: Here is my touch handler

Comment: it din't work because the timer not clear when function resetInterval() is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example without React Native:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            displayVideo: false,
            timer: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const timer = setInterval( () => {
            console.log("componentDidMount - show video");
            this.updateState(true);
        }, 10000);
        
        this.setState({ timer: timer })
    }

    resetInterval = () => {
        console.log("resetInterval working...");
        
        clearInterval(this.state.timer);

        const timer = setInterval( () => {
            console.log("reset timer - show video")
            this.updateState(true);
        }, 10000);
        
        this.setState({
            timer: timer,
            displayVideo: false
        });
    }

    updateState = (value) => {
        this.setState({ displayVideo: value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.resetInterval}>
                <div>Testing displayVideo: {this.state.displayVideo.toString()}</div>
            </div>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

What I did:

Your timer variable was out of scope where you were trying to use it.  You should save that in state.

You were not setting `displayVideo` to `false` anywhere so it was always going to be true.  I reused your `updateState` function to set the state to `true` or `false`

`this` was not defined in your `resetInterval` function.  You can either use an arrow function where `this` has lexical scope as I did, or use `resetInterval.bind(this)` to have `this` refer to the calling class there.

Hope this helps.